# Symfony Validator doesnt check DateTime correctly

Tags: php, json, validation, datetime, symfony

I´m using Validator to check my var´s. One of my them is an Object `SeminarDate` which includes `startDate` and `endDate`. My idea was to check the date´s with the Symfony Validator. However, it doesnt work. As example: "+0200StackOverflow" is valid date...

part of action in controller

```
foreach($dataReq['date'] as $key_a => $a) {
            $SeminarDate = new SeminarDate;
            $SeminarDate->setStartDate(new \DateTime($a['startdate']));
            $SeminarDate->setEndDate(new \DateTime($a['enddate']));
            $SeminarDates[] = $SeminarDate;

            $errors = $validator->validate($SeminarDate);
            if(count($errors)>0){
                $errorString = (string) $errors;
                return new View($errorString);
            }
        }
```

part of validation yml:

```
seminarDate:
            - Collection:
                fields:
                    startDate:
                        - Required:
                            - NotBlank:
                                message: 'startdate is required.'
                            - DateTime: ~

                    endDate:
                        - Required:
                            - DateTime: ~
                            - NotBlank:
                                message: 'endDate ist required.'
```

Example ( Sending JSON file to Controller):

```
"date" : [
    { "startdate": "+0200Stackoverflow",
      "enddate" : "+0200Stackoverlfow"
    }
],
```

If u need more, ask.
Thanks

Comment: Its not sympony it is `DateTime` class that interprets the input parameter. That is valid to: `new DateTime('now');`    http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.construct.php

Comment: clear .... thanks....

Comment: `print date('Y-m-d H:is',strtotime('+0200Stackoverflow'));#result 1970-01-01 01:0000` is what happens here. you get valid date from DateTime, but it must not valid at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did so, that i just createt a new validator and check the string itself before i add it to my Doctrine Class.

```
foreach($getData['date'] as $key => $value) {
            $validator = Validation::createValidator();
            if(!isset($value['startdate'])){
                return new View('startdate doesnt exist.');
            } elseif(!isset($value['enddate'])){
                return new View('enddate doesnt exist.');
            }
            foreach($value as $value1){
                $violations = $validator->validate($value1, array(
                    new NotBlank(),
                    new DateTime(),
                ));
                if (count($violations)>0) {
                    return new View('date isnt valid!');
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should install the php intl extension for proper date validation to work.

Check this https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup

You can go here
http://localhost:8000/config.php
 to see if you have it, or in your phpinfo.